# Dingo Api throttling based on User

Tags: php, laravel-5, dingo-api

I wanted to limit the API request specific to user in Laravel Application. 
I tried to following code to create custom throttle mentioned in https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Rate-Limiting#custom-throttles

```
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Dingo\Api\Http\RateLimit\Throttle\Throttle;

class CustomThrottle extends Throttle
{
    public function match(Container $app)
    {
        // Perform some logic here and return either true or false depending on whether
        // your conditions matched for the throttle.
    }
}
```

I tried to add this code:

```
'throttling' => [
    'custom' => new CustomThrottle(['limit' => 200, 'expires' => 10])
]
```

in Middleware in Kernel.php. But the IDE is throwing error stating `Expressions not allowed`

How can I create API throttle based on user in Laravel using Dingo?